# How can i resolve this error - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm failing to create this table

```
CREATE TABLE `destinations` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `code` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `menu_code` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `menu_position` int(50),
  `status` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `price` DOUBLE(50) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: You could have easily put this into an online syntax checker and validator, but you dont set lengths on types of double.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html
```

The use of the words reserved by MySQL as column names.

After you changed the name to covered `` the above does not work but you have an error in line 9.
check the definition for DOUBLE

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below - you don't need to specify data length for int type

```
CREATE TABLE `destinations` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `code` int NOT NULL,
  `menu_code` int NOT NULL,
  `menu_position` int,
  `status` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL);
```